# (autoit)sending random words from text file but it gives errors

Tags: autoit

hello im trying to read and write (send) text from words text file but it gives me bunch of errors i'm kinda newbie please be gentle to me thank you so much.

```
$File = FileReadToArray("words.txt")
$RandomWords = $File[Random(0, UBound($File) - 1, 1)]

send ("$RandomWords")
sleep (1000)
send ("{enter}")
```

Comment: Can you post the errors? You should remove quotes from around "$RandomWords" but that won't give any errors. After that fix, the code works for me.

Answer (score 2):

I'm certain there are better ways of doing it but if you're wanting to send one random line from a text file, this should work.

```
#include <file.au3>

$File = "words.txt"
$Lines = _FileCountLines($File)
$word = FileReadLine($File, Random(0, $Lines))

Run("notepad.exe")
WinWaitActive("Untitled - Notepad")
Send($word)
```

This will select the random line and send it to notepad.